# Firebug is displaying lots of undefined entries in a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, firebug

I'm working on customizing `<select>`'s. But I got stuck behind a problem. A quick `console.log(options);` shows the array's result:

> [undefined, undefined, "Selena Gomez", "Mila Kunis", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "Miley Cyrus"]

Also when I do `alert(options.length);` the result is 12. When in reality there are 4 options in the select..

Code that produces the array:

```
var options = new Array;               
$(this).children('option').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        options[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
    }
});
console.log(options);
```

I have no clue what is the issue.. I added the `if ($(this).val())`, to be sure, that no static gets in the array, but still.

**Note:** However, when I open the array up in firebug, it only shows the correct entries.

Comment: Are the values of the options non-linear starting from 0? (ie. 0, 2, 3, 11)

Comment: Also, if $(this).val() won't work for a valid value of "0"

Comment: @Detect: That part there, is for these guys: `<option value="">Emptyness</option>`

Comment: @Kalle, then you need to be more explicit in your if...`if($(this).val() !== "")` or `if($(this).val().length)`

Comment: You can use `[]` instead of `new Array` - looks way prettier.

Comment: @Detect: Of course, thanks, that makes perfect sense. missingno: Thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: @missingno not only is it prettier, it is also recommended (by Douglas Crockford)

Comment: Are text-based keys in javascript array actually allowed? Detect answered below.. Thanks to everybody! Things are very clear now. I will go back to work.

Comment: No. They are only allowed in objects. There is no distinction in PHP, but in JavaScript it very much matters.

Comment: @Frits van Campen - **all** keys in javascript are strings, they are never anything else. Arrays are just objects with a special length property and some handy methods, otherwise they are just objects.

Comment: @RobG very much not so. arrays are very different from objects. Do you have evidence to back up your claim?

Comment: @Frits - yes, very so. Check ECMA-262. If you want to check that the properties are strings: `var a = []; a[0] = 0; for (var p in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(p)) alert(p + ' is a ' + typeof p); // 0 is a string`

Comment: @RobG That's just because you're using the for-in construction, the key is always a string. It get's coerced back into an integer if you were to use it as an index. And you shouldn't use for-in on Arrays, just use a for-loop.

Comment: @Frits - for..in doesn't change them to strings, they are strings already, read ECMA-262 sect. 11.2.1. and you'll see that expressions used for property accessors are converted to string. For..in isn't used with arrays because it returns properties in an implementation dependent order, not because it changes property names to strings (they're already strings). I've shown that property names are strings, what is your evidence that they're numbers?

Comment: Section 11.2.1 talks about Property Accessors (version June 2011). So it's about objects, not arrays. There is no evidence that they are numbers other than that they behave like numbers. Arrays are sequential and ordered, objects are not. Sorting strings yields a different order compared to sorting integers: `1, 11, 2` vs `1, 2, 11`. So even if they are strings at some point I would argue that it's completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this).val()` must not be 0, 1, 2, 3 then, but rather 2, 3, 11 (where is the 4th?)

Use `options.push($(this).text());` instead or use it as an object to avoid auto generation of missing indexes.

Also, `$(this).val()` will evaluate to `false` if it is empty `""` or `0`, is that the 4th one perhaps?

Comment: Of course. That makes perfect sense. I'm more into php and don't know the basics of JS. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `$(this).val()` for the `$(this).text()` 'Selena Gomez' is the number 2 and 'Miley Cyrus' is 11.  Try this instead:

```
options.push($(this).text()); // ensure that your array is filled as an array
```

For example, this is okay in javascript

```
var a = [];
a[4] = 'test';
a["something"] = this;
```

and console.log will show

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 'test']
```

Comment: Thanks, for th quick reply. Frits beat ya do it, but hope +1 gets your smile on :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var options = [];               
$(this).children('option').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        options.push($(this).text());
    }
});
console.log(options.join(","));
```

If you want text keys then use a javascript object as an associative array.

```
var options = {};               
$(this).children('option').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        options[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
    }
});
$.each(options, function(key, value) { 
    console.log(key + ': ' + value); 
});
```

Comment: This actually works really good, but I need the keys in the array. Are text-based keys in js based array actually allowed?

Comment: @Kalle, allowed, yes, but you have to `$.each` or `for(x in options)` loop thru `options` to get the items in the key-based array to avoid the undefined items

Comment: @Detect: Understandable. Anyways, I need those non-linear keys now, but I think I got the fix. So thanks.

Comment: @Kalle: is this what you want?

Comment: Basically, what is the trick behind `var options = {};`? But it still leaves one undefined entry at the end..

Comment: @Kalle: its a short hand notation of `var options = new Object();` One undefined entry at the end? could you show the exact log at the last iteration?

Comment: Oh, my bad actually. Had an old alert(); there :$ Thanks man, that one step closer to the goal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misleading responses here:

1. Javascript array indexes are strings. Arrays are just objects with a special length property and some handy methods, but otherwise they are just objects. Their properties are strings. Numeric properties will be treated as indexes and are used to set the length property.
2. There are no "missing keys". If you create a sparse array, its length will be set to the highest index + 1. If you iterate over all indexes from 0 to length -1, then any that don't exists will return *undefined*

e.g.

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 'zero';
a[4] = 'four';
console.log(a.length); // 5
console.log(a); // ["zero", undefined, undefined, undefined, "four"]
console.log(a[1]);     // undefined
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(1)); // false
```

Just because Firebug lists idexes 1 to 3 inclusive as *undefined* does not mean they exist.

A simple loop version of the OP is:

```
var opts = this.options;
for (var i=0, iLen=opts.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (opts[i].value) {
    options[opts[i].value] = opts[i].text;
  }
}
```